# Dropdown(Template) gets invisible after clicking another objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dropdown, visible

example [image: here]

i am using a *Inputfield* to filter or search the **dropdown list items**, Dropdown by default gets **invisible** of after single click. i need it to be **visible** till the options are selected, thankyou from heart in advance :)

Comment: Then don't use the Dropdown but implement a simple panel with buttons you can Instantiate and remove 
or activate and deactivate dynamically? See [`ScrollRect`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-ScrollRect.html) and [`VerticalLayoutGroup`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-VerticalLayoutGroup.html)

Comment: thankyou @derHugo  but its a bit complicated and cant modify now, cant i achieve what i needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
 using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class DropdownFilter : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private InputField inputField;

    [SerializeField]
    private Dropdown dropdown;

    private List<Dropdown.OptionData> dropdownOptions;

    private void Start()
    {
        dropdownOptions = dropdown.options;
    }
    public void FilterDropdown(string input)
    {
        dropdown.options = dropdownOptions.FindAll(option => option.text.IndexOf(input) >= 0);
    }
}
```

1. Create a new script called DropdownFilter.cs Copy-paste the
   following script

   2. Create the input field and dropdown UI elements
   3. Attach the script to the gameObject you want (an empty in your scene or the dropdown, or the input field, ...) you just have to make sure the gameObject is enabled when the scene starts
   4. Drag & drop the inputfield and dropdown in the appropriate fields in the inspector, when the gameObject holding the script is selected
   5. Add a new event in the OnValueChanged of the input field. Drag & drop the gameObject created step #5 (holding the DropdownFilter script) and select the FilterDropdown function (`DynamicString`)

Comment: which will probably still automatically close the Dropdown when clicking on anything else like e.g. the InputField ;)

Comment: Also I think it is more efficient to use `dropDownOptions.Select(option => option.text.Contains(input)).ToList();`